# Is there a way to initialize a remote git repository using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, push, init, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit interface to work with my git server. TortoiseGit has only one way to initialize repository "Git create repository here...", but this option only initialize local which means I cannot push remote, because the repository doesn't existe in the server. Is there any way to create a remote repository using TortoiseGit interface? For example, create and initialize the same respository local and remote which would make possible to push without need to connect to the server and create manually there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on how you host your remote. For example on GitHub, you must first create the repo through the web interface.

Comment: I understand that. My remote is in the same network as the users. What I wanted to know if there is an option in TortoiseGit context menu that the people could with a right mouse click already initialize the git repository local and remote at the same time to be already done for push and no need to access the git server to create the remote before.